# Exclude Search Results in Keepass2

Tags: windows-7, keepass

I use [Keepass2](http://keepass.info/download.html) search feature extensively, how ever what annoys me is when searching for a password, I get results found in the backup folder, the backup folder contains old passwords and aren't relevant. Is it possible to exclude items found in the backup folder from showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [keepass forum thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/c28a2f19) they say:

> In KeePass 2.x, to exclude a group from search:  right click on the
>   group, select ***Edit Group***, select the ***Behavior*** tab, change "***Searching
>   entries in this group:***" to Disabled.

I didn't try that, but it seems that it's working according to the replies to that thread...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else got here searching for KeePassXC instead of Keepass2:

Similar to [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/661687/748546) by [MikO](https://superuser.com/users/214783/miko), you would right click on the group, select **Edit Group**, and in the **Group** tab set the **Search** drop-down to **Disable**.